# Inheritance in Javascript using prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

i am trying to use my parent function to have a value. this is probably silly question but I haven't been able to find a straight to point tutorial on how to do it.

I know that while using prototype it is possible to

```
function handler (selector) {
    return selector;
}
 Object.prototype.alertLine = function () {
        alert(this);}

handler('hello').alertLine();
```

and still receive an alert. but i want to know if there is a way to specify the object,sting,number in the parent function eg

```
function handler(selector) {
if (typeof(selector) == 'string'){
return String(selector);
}

if (typeof(selector) == 'number') {
 return Number(selector);
}

if (typeof (selector) == 'object') {
 return Object(selector);
}
}

handler.prototype.alertLine = function () {
 alert(this);
}

handler('hello').alertLine();
```

I don't mind if `Handler` is an object or not it only matters if i am pass values using this method.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"The idea is for the person to reinitialize a new object every time in one line of code so instead of var a = new Handler('hello'); a.alertLine(); instead of this I want to change to this var a = new Handler; then reference to a new parameter each time a('hello').alertLine()"*

I'm not really sure why you want to do it like that but something like this may help you:

```
var Handler = function() {
    var fun = function() {}
    fun.prototype.set = function(t) {this.t = t; return this;}
    fun.prototype.alertLine = function(){ alert(this.t); }
    return new fun;  
}

var a = Handler(); 
a.set('foo').alertLine();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/herostwist/yPSpT/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like that you need to instantiate an object of handler, not user it as a method.  You want a [function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

```
function Handler(selector){

 if (typeof(selector) == 'string'){
  this.selector = String(selector);
 }

 if (typeof(selector) == 'number') {
  this.selector = Number(selector);
 }

 if (typeof (selector) == 'object') {
  this.selector = Object(selector);
 }

}

Handler.prototype.alertLine = function(){
  alert(this.selector);
}

var h = new Handler("hello");
h.alertLine();
```